# Java 8 Filter set based on another set

Tags: java, java-8

*Using Java 8 new constructs*, such as streams for example, is there a way to filter a `Set` based on the order in another collection?

```
Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>();

persons.add(new Person("A", 23));
persons.add(new Person("B", 27));
persons.add(new Person("C", 20));

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("B");
names.add("A");
```

I want to filter items from set `persons` based on `names`, such that only those persons who have their names specified in `names` will be retained, but in the order that they appear in `names`.

So, I want

```
Set<Person> filteredPersons = ...;
```

where 1st element is `Person("B", 27)` and 2nd element is `Person("A", 23)`.

If I do the following,

```
Set<Person> filteredPersons = new HashSet<>(persons);
filteredPersons = filteredPersons.stream().filter(p -> names.contains(p.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

the order is not guaranteed to be the same as in `names`, if I am not mistaken.

I know how to achieve this using a simple *for* loop; I'm just looking for a java 8 way of doing it.

Thanks for looking!

**EDIT:**

The *for* loop that achieves the same result:

```
Set<Person> filteredPersons = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (String name : names) {
  for (Person person : persons) {
    if (person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
      filteredPersons.add(person);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The `LinkedHashSet` implementation ensures that the order is maintained.

Comment: Sets in general are unordered, so you can't expect your result set to have an specific order.  It is possible if you collect to a list.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a `SortedSet` rather than a `Set`?

Comment: Can there be more than 2 people having the same name?

Comment: HashSet has no defined order, so it doesn't mean anything to attempt to retain the order.

Comment: @Tunaki the list will not contain duplicate names.
PeterLawrey, Matthew I am open to changing the set implementation, for example to a LinkedHashSet as shown in the example above to achieve the final goal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
final Set<Person> persons = ...
Set<Person> filteredPersons = names.stream()
    .flatMap(n -> 
        persons.stream().filter(p -> n.equals(p.getName()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Collect the streams of persons created by filtering them by each name. This is fast for situations like the example provided, but will scale linearly with the number of persons, like O(N*P).

For larger collections of persons and names, creating an index that can be used to look up a person by name will be faster overall, scaling as O(N+P):

```
Map<String, Person> index = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
Set<Person> filteredPersons = names.stream()
    .map(index::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on _why_ this code solves the OPs issue?

Comment: This indeed solves my issue. I am just a little bit unsure about its efficiency as compared to the other solution that uses a map given above.
If I understand correctly, the `persons` filter operation will be carried out for each _n_, similar to a nested for loop?

Comment: @HP Yes, you are right. I added another approach for large collections which uses a map, but in a more efficient way than Helder Pereira's solution. His approach performs two hash look ups, which is slower than one lookup followed by a null test. If the number of names is smaller than some limit, the first solution will still be faster than building a map.

Answer (score 3):

> I am open to changing the set implementation, for example to a
>   LinkedHashSet as shown in the example above to achieve the final goal.

If you are completely open to change the data structure used to store the `persons`, then you should probably consider using a `Map`, as it would improve a lot the efficiency of your algorithm.

```
Map<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();

persons.put("A", new Person("A", 23));
persons.put("B", new Person("B", 27));
persons.put("C", new Person("C", 20));

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("B");
names.add("A");

List<Person> filteredPersons = names.stream()
        .map(persons::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the letter case may be different in `persons` and `names`, you can do a `.toLowerCase()` in the keys of the `Map`.

Comment: There could be a problem if `names` would contain name of person which doesn't appear in `persons` like `"D"`. In that case we would end up with `null` and later probably NPE. `flatMap` and `filter` combination shown in erickson's answer doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I think that was not mentioned by the OP, but it's easy to fix: either add `.filter(persons::containsKey)` before the `.map` or `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` after.

Comment: True, it wasn't mentioned by OP but it wasn't also negated by him which is why it is worth mentioning (you can add solutions from your comment to your answer just to be safe).

Comment: I don’t like querying a map twice; that’s a waste of resources. So I’d rather prefer `.map(persons::get) .filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like following (not tested):

```
.sorted((p1, p2) ->
        Integer.compare(names.indexOf(p1.getName()),
                        names.indexOf(p2.getName())))
```

And, as mentionned above, collect to a `List` instead of a `Set`.

---

As mentionned in comment by Alexis, you can also write this more concisely:

```
.sorted(comparingInt(p -> names.indexOf(p.getName())))
```

Where `comparingInt` comes from a `static import` of `Comparator`.

Comment: You can avoid a bit the boilerplate of the comparator with (a static import) `.sorted(comparingInt(p -> names.indexOf(p.getName())))`